# Apache2 wont start, error code

Tags: apache2, mysql

New to ubunutu, installed mysql for Kodi and configured, now I am working on Owncloud and as I am working through install, Apache doesn't want to play nice. Here is `journalctl -xe` results:

```
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server apachectl[16967]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. S
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server apachectl[16967]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server apachectl[16967]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server apachectl[16967]: no listening sockets available, shutting down    
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server apachectl[16967]: AH00015: Unable to open logs    
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server apachectl[16967]: Action 'start' failed.    
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server apachectl[16967]: The Apache error log may have more information.    
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1    
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.    
Sep 01 07:50:25 Kodi-Server systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Here is result of lsof -i:80

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   7241     root    6u  IPv4 1656474      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7241     root    7u  IPv6 1656475      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7242 www-data    6u  IPv4 1656474      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7242 www-data    7u  IPv6 1656475      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7243 www-data    6u  IPv4 1656474      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7243 www-data    7u  IPv6 1656475      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7244 www-data    6u  IPv4 1656474      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7244 www-data    7u  IPv6 1656475      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7245 www-data    6u  IPv4 1656474      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   7245 www-data    7u  IPv6 1656475      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Port 80 seems to be in use already. You can find out which process is using it with `lsof -i:80`.

Comment: nginx is using that port make apache use another port

Comment: @PerlDuck Sorry, Learning as I go.

Comment: @Thomas Output updated. Thank you for direction.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Ok I will explore that, thank you.

Comment: @ShaneGreenfield Sure, you are welcome. Same applies to me :-)

Comment: I would check the /var/log directory for apache logs, as it gives more detailed explanation why it is not starting up.

Comment: @kukulo In general you are right but in this particular case the message is quite clear: `… Address already in use: … could not bind to address [::]:80`. I'd either configure `ngnix` or `apache` to use another port. I personally would re-configure apache to, say, 8080, because I have no idea on how to configure nginx ;-)

Comment: That was it, changed port and I am good to go. Thank you as always!